# SimpleExoPlayer black screen bug？

Tags: android

im using the SimpleExoPlayer in my android project and got this problem. i have two activities, naming a and b, that a jumps to b and. Both a and b have their own playerview but using the same player(by singleton). The app starts with a activity and the player works with video and sound, and the same with b when it jumps to b. However when jumping back, the playerview in a activity only plays sounds with black screen. How to fix this bug? Begging for anwsers

Answer (score 1):

Code for init player

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                        new DefaultDataSourceFactory(requireContext(), requireContext().getPackageName());
                ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(upload.getUploads().getUrl() + ".mp4"));
                LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
                Log.e("///////////", "VIDEO URL=" + upload.getUploads().getUrl());
                player.prepare(loopingSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

In your onPause method add player.setPlayWhenReady(false); and in your onResume again initialize player and use